Using modular arithmetic to show that an equation has no integer solutions
I have an equation of the form $ax^4+by^4=z^2$ and I want to show that there is no triple of integers $(x,y,z)$ different from $(0,0,0)$ that satisfies this equation. My professor suggests that we look at this equation modulo different primes and find one for which it does not have solution. My problem is that, whenever I look at this equation modulo a prime, the case where the three numbers modulo that prime is $0$ is always a possible solution that I cannot discard. Thus, I feel like modular arithmetic will never help me with this problem. Can someone tell me how to use it properly/give me other strategies to approach this problem?
N.b. $a$ and $b$ are fixed integers in my problem

Are $a,b$ fixed? If not then say $a=3$, $b=x=y=1$, $z=2$ is a solution.

How do you apply modular arithmetic if there are $a$, $b$, which could be anything?

@Sahaj yes, they are fixed

@Aig thank you for your comment. They are indeed fixed intgers

Please specify what the value of $a$ and $b$ are

@kubo you should put it in the question too. I dont think there's any general way to proceed for any $a$ and $b$.

The usual way to handle the case where $x \equiv y \equiv z \equiv 0 \mod p$ is to use infinite descent. The idea for this problem would be to choose a prime $p$, then it follows that $p^4|(ax^4+by^4)$, so $p^4|z^2$ from which follows $p^2|z$. So now we see that with
$$x'=\frac{x}p,\; y'=\frac{y}p,\; z'=\frac{z}{p^2}$$
the triple $(x',y',z')$ is also a solution of the equation, and each component is smaller than in the original triple $(x,y,z)$, unless$ (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$.
So either you started with $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ which is a valid solution, but we know that, or you will (after potentially repeating this procedure for some time) arrive at a solution where not all of $x,y,z$ are divisible by $p$.
If you can prove using modular arithmetic that such a case cannot happen, you also proved that there cannot be a non-trivial solution with $x \equiv y \equiv z \equiv 0 \mod p$, because each such solution could be reduced, via the above method, to one where at least one of $x,y,z$ is not divisible by $p$.
